# How to numerically solve difference equations in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-methods, difference-equations

I am trying to learn how to solve difference equations (also called recurrence relations) using python.

The problem in question is the equation

```
$x_{n+2} - 4x_{n+1} - x_{n} = 0$       where x_0 = 1 and x_1 = 1
```

Which outputs the sequence: n =     1, 1, 5, 21, 89, 377, ....

I have solved the problem by using math to find the general expression for this sequence, and then defining it as a function in python - and made it work (kind of).

However, my reason for posting this is that I think there are better ways to do this and that the solution I mentioned above is suboptimal.

After looking at a few similar examples, like how to numerically compute the Fibonacci sequence,
i tried to generalize this method and modify it to the problem I'm working on hoping that it would work. And it kind of did, but not quite.

The solution I came up with is:

```
from numpy import zeros

N = 100
x = zeros(N+1, int)

x[0] = 1
x[1] = 1

for n in range(2, N+1):
    x[n] = x[n-2] + 4*x[n-1]
    print(f"x[{n}] = {x[n]}")

##produces wrong calculations after x[15]##
```

**So my two questions are:**

1. Is there a general and "solid" way of solving these kinds of problems? If so, does anyone have any examples they would like to share?
2. Why am I getting weird results after x[15]? And is there anyone who can help me fix it?

The out-print is supposed to be

```
Iteration    sequence output
===========================
x[0]        1
x[1]        1 
x[2]        5
x[3]        21
x[4]        89
x[5]        377
x[6]        1597
x[7]        6765 
…….
x[100]  137347080577163458295919672868222343249131054524487463986003968
```

And I’m getting:

```
x[0]        1
x[1]        1 
x[2]        5
x[3]        21
x[4]        89
x[5]        377
x[6]        1597
x[7]        6765
...
x[15] = 701408733
…….
x[16] = -1323752223
x[17] = -298632863
x[18] = 1776683621
x[19] = -1781832971
...
x[100] = -855830631
```

Comment: The terms of a recurrence are easily computed the obvious way, x[n]= f(x[n-1], x[n-2], ... x[n-k]). The weird values that you find are due to overflow. The solution is close to x[n]=c 4.236^n, which grows very fast, more than two additional bits on every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy was developed for fast operations on arrays of numbers. This means that the type hint gets translated into a numpy-internal number type of fixed bit length. One can abuse numpy for operations on other object by defining `dtype=object`, but this will in general not be faster than list and iterator based solutions.

You define the type of the numpy zeros array as `int`, which apparently gets cast as 32 bit integers. Thus you get results in the limitations of the 32 bit integers with overflow folding into the negative range. Check with `print(x.dtype)`, you should get `int32` or, as with me in python3, `int64`.

Python's built-in integer objects that are used automatically in all integer operations have a multi-precision or bigint type, but that is not very compatible with numpy. Try

```
x=(N+1)*[0]
```

or list construction by appending as numpy-free alternative. Then with only this change your code produces

```
x[14] = 165580141
x[15] = 701408733
x[16] = 2971215073
x[17] = 12586269025
...
x[30] = 1779979416004714189
x[31] = 7540113804746346429
x[32] = 31940434634990099905
x[33] = 135301852344706746049
...
x[100] = 137347080577163115432025771710279131845700275212767467264610201
```

Comment: Really useful soulution! I'll keep it in mind for similar problems in the future:-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fredericoamigo: but notice that getting all these digits is probably of no use. Floating-point is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Difference equations are just recursive relationships. The mathematics behinds them can be quite tricky... finding the basis of the companion matrix, ... but you need a solid background. For that stuffs I suggest you `sympy`which is a mathematics package for symbolic manipulation.

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def diff_eq(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1: return 1
    return 4*diff_eq(n-1) + diff_eq(n-2)


for i in range(20):
    print(diff_eq(i))
```

Output

```
1
5
21
89
377
1597
6765
28657
121393
514229
2178309
9227465
39088169
165580141
701408733
2971215073
12586269025
53316291173
225851433717
```

To boost the recursion you can use the decorator `lru_cache` from the `functools`, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html): *memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls*. I am thankful to Nachiket for such suggestion.

For your second question: you forgot to add the error log: `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars`. If you use `np.int64` the maximum integer that you may achieve is 9223372036854775807.

Comment: In addition to the answer above, look into the ```lru_cache``` decorator from functools. This essentially avoids recomputation of the recursive function if it has been computed already, leading to speed up.

Comment: Thanks for providing a good example! I'll definitely try out sumpy as you suggested!